# jtable mouse event pop 2 times

Tags: java, jtable

I created an event that execute on table click ,that open a Joptionpane .
but the problem is the joptionpane pops up 2 times .
keep in mind that , i am adding the event after i generate the table 
like this click(table0),  the tables are generated after retriving from DB and some calculations .

her is the code for the event

```
 protected void click(JTable table)
{   
    JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane();



    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


            if(!combo_chau.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("station"))
                pane.setViewportView(tab_mat(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString(),table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString()));
                if(combo_chau.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("station"))
                {pane.setViewportView(tab_sta(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString(),table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()));
                 if(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().equals("sans detail"))
                 {   pane.setViewportView(tab_sta_sansdetail(combo_cam.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                    if(combo_cam.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("tout"))
                        pane.setViewportView(tab_sta(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString(),table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()));
                 }
                }

            if(table.getModel().getColumnName(((JTable) e.getSource()).getSelectedColumn()).equals("autre") )
            {       int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    frame, 
                    pane,
                    "Use a Panel",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling your `protected void click(JTable table)` method only once on each table because you will add a new listener every time you are calling it.

Another issue might be that you are using `mousePressed` which reacts on the mouse press already, you should consider using `mouseClicked` instead to react only on a full click.